# Open file content in new tab in browser

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I want to show the file content in new tab in browser. What i have done is this:

```
int BUFF_SIZE = 102400;
FileInputStream  is = null;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];
int a = -1; 

try
{
    is = new FileInputStream(file);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while((a = is.read(buffer)) != -1) 
    {
        out.write(buffer);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    ServletOutputStream os = null;
    os = response.getOutputStream();
    os.write(out.toByteArray());
    os.close();
    is.close();

}
catch(Exception e)
{
  // Exception handling
}
```

But this is leading to download of the file instead of opening the file-content in new tab.
I am not able to find what i am doing wrong.

Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all you should need to do now is add JQuery to your webpage, and use [JQUery.get](http://www.google.com/url?url=http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/&rct=j&frm=1&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ei=LHj7U6S6GdH_yQSq4YG4CQ&ved=0CBQQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNH4i2n-7A7w04IMXMsYQ5RRjSEeNw). Once you get the html from the servlet, use jquery or javascript to set the text in your tab.

BTW, you might want to set other details on the servlet output stream, like file type, length etc. Just a thought

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this with the omnifaces library

```
Faces.sendFile(file, false);//true makes it as an attachment
```

more information on http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/1.8/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#sendFile(java.io.File,%20boolean)

Answer (score 0):

A web application might not even know what is a brower. It receives requests through HTTP protocol and send responses through same protocol. The protocol by itsels knows nothing about browsers and tabs.

You must use javascript for anything that happens at browser level. Other answers adviced you to use jQuery. It is a well known javascript library that hides differences between browsers, but there are others around (dojo, extJs, ...) : Google and make your choice.

By the way, if all you want is open an URL in a new tab, that's one of the very few operations that you can do at HTML level. Just look at this example 
from [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) :

```
 <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools!</a>
```

that opens `www.w3schools.com` in a new tab (if browser has tabs what is now common) or a new window.